# Почему может не правильно определяться mime тип jpeg?

Tags: php

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста. Почему может не правильно определяться mime тип jpeg?

```php
$image = base64_decode($value);

$f = finfo_open();

dd(
  $value,
  finfo_buffer($f, $image, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE),
  $image
);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

должен прийти image/jpeg а приходит octet-stream

Comment: нужно явно указывать тип данных в заголовке HTTP ответа.

Comment: А зачем вам делать лишние операции? у вас же MIME-тип указан в самом `$value`.
`$mime = explode(':', $value)[1];`

Comment: нашел на просторах подобную реализацию валидации image в base 64